# How do i add a grey transparent background in this whole section?

Tags: html

so i've been trying out for over 2 hours different methods and i can't really find anything.

This is my HTML

```
    <section class="" style="background-image: url(assets/img/bg3test.png) ; background-position: center center; background-size: cover; background-repeat: ;">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row text-center" data-scrollreveal="enter bottom over 2.0s">
                <div class="col-lg-12">
                    <h2 style="color:white">Some thoughts</h2>
                    <hr class="light">
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-12">
                    <ul id="clients-carousel" class="text-center">
                        <li class="item">
                            <img class="img-responsive" src="assets/img/u1.png" alt="">
                            <p style="color:white; font-weight:bold "> "</p>            
                        </li>
                        <li class="item">
                            <img class="img-responsive" src="assets/img/u2.jpg" alt="">
                            <p style="color:white; font-weight:bold "> "</p>    
                        </li>
                        <li class="item">
                            <img class="img-responsive" src="assets/img/u3.jpg" alt="">
                            <p style="color:white; font-weight:bold "> "</p>
                        </li>
                        <li class="item">
                            <img class="img-responsive" src="assets/img/u4.jpg" alt="">
                                <p style="color:white; font-weight:bold "> "</p>
                        </li>
                      <li class="item">
                            <img class="img-responsive" src="assets/img/u5.jpg" alt="">
                                <p style="color:white; font-weight:bold "> "</p>
                        </li>

                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
```

So i'm trying to make it so that the whole section has a general black or greyish background so it looks nicer, but i've been trying out recently and it hasn't worked out well.

I've tried various css methods too like

```
.testi
```

{
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 1000px rgba(0,0,0,.2);

}

and

```
background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd use this css:

```
section {
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.8)
}
```

It should work, unless the section tag is collapsing to a zero height.

Answer (score 0):

Add .testi class to your main section.

css:

```
.testi{ 
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 1000px rgba(0,0,0,.2);
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
}
```

Comment: Hi minal, i've tried this. But is there a way to make it so the background has a opacity ?

Comment: yes, it is possible to add background  opacity. you can set value in rgba(0,0,0,0.5) -- here 0.5 is opactiy of your background color